# XML string to Object

Tags: java, xml, list, collections, xml-parsing

I got this **string**:

```
<GetTimetableEntriesResponse Result="Success">
    <Timetable>
        <TimetableEntryGroup TimetableEntryGroupId="1739" ChannelId="263" Name="Ablauf 1" Priority="10">
            <StartDateTime>07.07.2016 13:52:31</StartDateTime>
            <SortOrder>2</SortOrder>
        </TimetableEntryGroup>
        <TimetableEntryGroup TimetableEntryGroupId="1740" ChannelId="263" Name="Ablauf 2" Priority="10">
            <StartDateTime>07.07.2016 00:00:00</StartDateTime>
            <Recurrence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <pattern>Hourly</pattern>
                <interval>1</interval>
                <start>36000</start>
                <duration>600</duration>
            </Recurrence>
            <SortOrder>3</SortOrder>
        </TimetableEntryGroup>
    </Timetable>
</GetTimetableEntriesResponse>
```

and I have to parse it to a `List<TimetableEntryGroup>`.

I don't know how I should do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/).

You can find enough examples here on SO too.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, as it doesn't solve the question